# How to get the Pre-compiled source code in codeblocks?

Tags: c, codeblocks, precompile

There are some `#define` statements in my C language code, and now i find some bug.
But the codeblocks IDE can not step into the #define block.

so i want to get the  Pre-compiled source code, which will expand the `#define` macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [-E](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) option of gcc, you can expand the macros to a C file, and then compile the C file.